# Formatting my numbers with leading zeros with knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I would like to format my numbers with leading zeros when needed:

Example:

1 >> 01

5 >> 05

10 >> 10

I've tried this:

```
<td data-bind="text: ProjectId.toString('00')"></td>
```

Where `ProjectId` is the property containing my number.

But it doesn't work. I get the error `Number.prototype.toString: invalid argument`

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-create-a-zerofilled-value-using-javascript), use use the zeroFill function to add leading zeros.

```
vm.paddedProjectId = ko.computed(function() {
return vm.zeroFill(vm.ProjectId());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For very simple cases this should [work](http://jsfiddle.net/FU2pV/):

```html
<span data-bind="text: ProjectId < 10 ? '0' + ProjectId.toString() : ProjectId"></span>
```

Or [move this logic](http://jsfiddle.net/FU2pV/1/) to your model instead:

```
vm.paddedProjectId = ko.computed(function() {
    return vm.ProjectId < 10 ? '0' + vm.ProjectId.toString() : vm.ProjectId;
});
```

This won't work for numbers below zero, nor will it pick up a dynamic number of zero's (e.g. if your numbers go beyond 100 you may want "005", etc). It may also have some iffy results with unexpected values for `ProjectId`, such as [the empty string](http://jsfiddle.net/FU2pV/2/). For those cases refer to the [question mentioned in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1267283/419956).

PS. The function you're using is [Number.toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) that expects a *radix* argument; useful in its own right but not quite what you're looking for I think.